# How to detect the end of a crop row with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, photogrammetry

I am writing a program to detect crop rows in uav imagery and I have successfully managed to detect crop rows in cropped sections of the image using opencv and python, however the issue I am running into now is how to go about detecting the end of a crop row.

The image is of a field(Cant share it publicly) and I am attempting to detect all the rows in that field, I can detect the rows however currently I am simply draw the line along the row from the top to bottom of the image. Instead I would like draw this line from the start to end of the crop row.

i.e. smething like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUkg6.jpg (Not enough rep to post images yet)
But essentially I need to detect the end of the row so I can draw the line to the just the end of the row.

Any Ideas on how this might be done?

Comment: This is going to be really difficult to answer without some more context as to what exactly the issue is. Can you share maybe an example image (not necessarily the one you are working on) that better showcases the problem?

Comment: added an example

Comment: Ok. I'm assuming you're using Hough transforms for the row detection?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Probabilistic Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

frame = cv2.imread("crop.jpg")
# It converts the BGR color space of image to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Threshold of blue in HSV space
lower_green = np.array([21, 115, 0])
upper_green = np.array([179, 255, 255])

# preparing the mask to overlay
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)

mask = cv2.blur(mask, (5,5))
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

edges = cv2.Canny(mask,100,200)

# The black region in the mask has the value of 0,
# so when multiplied with original image removes all non-blue regions
result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)

cdst = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 100, 30)

if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        cv2.line(cdst, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdst)
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)

cv2.waitKey(-1)
```